# sql distinct with multiple fields requried

Tags: sql, sybase, advantage-database-server

I'm using Advantage Database Server by Sybase.  I need to elimiate duplicate addbatch's from my report, but having trouble pulling up just distinct records.  Any idea what I am missing?

here is what I am using

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    SI.[addbatch] as [Batch#],
    SI.[current account #] as [Account],
    SI.[status date] as [Status Date],
    SI.[SKU] as [SKU],
    AC.[email address] as [Email]
FROM  salesinventory SI, accounts AC
WHERE  AC.[account #]=SI.[current account #] and [Status Date] > '6/1/2015'
```

I still get duplicate addbatch's though.  I'm not sure where I am going wrong!  Thanks in advance!  Wasn't even sure how to google this question!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the result you are getting?

Comment: Assuming a given `addbatch` has multiple SKUs (or any other column), of course you'll get back multiple rows for that `addbatch`. If you want distinct addbatch rows, you'll need to not include the values in the query that are causing the dupes.

Comment: @MartianCodeHound the results I get are:

Comment: @MartianCodeHound here are the results I get [link](http://postimg.org/image/tw730le23/)

Comment: @Andrew if I remove the rest of the selects it works fine, but i need those fields in my report for it to work.

Comment: OK, so for Batch 2158, which date would you like your report to use: 6/10/2015 or 6/02/2015?

Comment: @MartianCodeHound I see the hole in my idea.  I need to find a different field to work off of because addbatches can be transferred at any time separate from their group. Thanks for making me realize that!  I'll post back once I get back in the system.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to check uniqueness of a single column and that's not actually what your code is performing.  Try this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (SELECT SI.[addbatch] as [Batch#],
         SI.[current account #] as [Account],
         SI.[status date] as [Status Date],
         ETC,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Batch#]) AS RowNumber
     FROM   salesinventory SI, accounts AC
     WHERE  AC.[account #]=SI.[current account #] and [Status Date] > '6/1/2015') as rec
WHERE rec.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Hi @DarkNinja955,
I tried that and ended up with:
poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2115;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected lexical element not found: FROM You are missing the keyword FROM after the column definitions in your SELECT statement. There was a problem parsing the table 
names after the FROM keyword in your SELECT statement. -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 142 (line: 4 column: 43)

Comment: I have to ask, but did you replace "ETC" in the code with your remaining columns?

Answer (score 0):

-- The following code is generic to de-duplicate records, modify to suit your need.

```
select  x.[Well_Name] as nameX
      , x.[TestDate]  as dateX
from (
SELECT count(*) as dup
      ,[Well_Name]

      ,[TestDate]enter code here
  FROM [dbo].[WellTests]
  group by  [TestDate] ,[Well_Name] ) x
  where dup > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have unique batch numbers in your result, you have to GROUP BY the batch field **only**.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    SI.[addbatch] as [Batch#],
    MIN(SI.[current account #]) as [Account],
    MIN(SI.[status date]) as [Status Date],
    MIN(SI.[SKU]) as [SKU],
    MIN(AC.[email address]) as [Email]
FROM  salesinventory SI, accounts AC
WHERE  AC.[account #]=SI.[current account #] and [Status Date] > '6/1/2015'
GROUP BY
  SI.[addbatch]
```

You didn't say how you want to [aggregate](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/master_supported_aggregate_column_functions.htm) the other columns, just replace `MIN` with something that makes more sense for you, like `SUM` or `COUNT`, etc.

There is a topic about [grouping in the documentation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html?devguide_grouping_data.htm).

PS: `SELECT DISTINCT` is (basically) just a shorter way to `GROUP BY` on all columns *without any aggregation*.